# How to stream 360° 4k Videos for VR on Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 360 app for the Google Cardboard. I am using Unity 2018.3
By transcoding the Video in Unity it is possible to play a 4k video.

My problem comes, when trying to stream the video, since I don't know how to get the transcoded video to upload it.

Should I export the video into an asset bundle, upload that and unpack it on runtime, or is there a way to just upload the transcoded video directly?

Comment: AFAIK, Android smartphones with 4k resolution do not exist yet

Comment: The problem is, that the Video is a 360 degree Video, so it needs to be a high resolution, since the percieved resolution is ~1/4th of the actual resolution.

Comment: Fair enough. However, your issue still isn't very clear to me. You have an app, you have a huge video file, and you want to play this video in your app. Where is transcoding intervening here ? If you look at [tutorials for Video360 an Android](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/video360) this should be transparent to you.

Comment: Most android devices are not able to render 4k on their own. It is possible to get around this by setting Transcode to true in the import settings for the video in Unity. When doing that it is possible to play the video in full resolution on devices, that can not render 4k.
The problem appears, when trying to stream the video. The only way I know to get the Transcoded video is to use an asset bundle. The tutorials for Video360 only deal with 4k in the context of Daydream Ready smartphones and not for cardboard.